# Find the schema from database for a table in DBeaver

Tags: sql-server, dbeaver

I am using DBeaver 22.0.1 for a client. I have access to test environment. The schema's in test and prod are little different. The client gave me the table name, but the schema is different from prod.

Is there a way to find the schema of that table using some shortcut?

Comment: Since you tagged this with sql server is it safe to assume your database is sql server?

Comment: I must admit, it seems odd that the schema name(s) are different in production and test. that would mean that any code you have would break when you transfer it, due to the schema defined in your SQL being incorrect. It seems like that is the real problem that needs addressing.

Comment: I have to agree with @Larnu. About the only way you could possibly manage not changing your code is with synonyms but depending on things that might not be possible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are just trying to find the name of the schema for a given table name you can use this query. But please note that if you have the same table name in more than 1 schema you will get all the schemas where this table name exists.

```
select s.name
from sys.tables t
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
where t.name = 'YourTableNameHere'
```